# Move rows from master table to child table with foreign key constraints

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, partitioning

I have a table called `posts` with ~10m rows and it's slowing down my query performance, so I was thinking of optimising it using partitioning to child tables, where each child table would contain a year worth of records.

I currently have the following strategy:

1. Create the child table without the `INHERIT` constraint by

   ```
   CREATE TABLE posts_2017 AS
   (SELECT * from posts where inserted_at < '2018-01-01 00:00:00');
   ```
2. Create the inheritance relationship afterwards by

   ```
   ALTER TABLE posts_2017 inherit posts;
   ```
3. Add the `CHECK` constraint to the child table afterwards

Now it works well but now if I query `SELECT * from posts` I would get duplicate results for the 2017 posts. My next step is to delete them from the master table using another query

```
DELETE FROM ONLY posts where inserted_at < '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
```

but I have hit another roadblock where another table actually has a foreign key referencing those 2017 records.

For instance, say I have a table `users_posts` with only `user_id` and `post_id` column and my delete query would fail if a row in this table references a 2017 post.

What are my options in this scenario?

Comment: Why do you think that partitioning would improve the query performance?

Comment: Cause right now any queries would be performed on the ~10m rows where my app mostly only needs to access the more recent posts. If I can partition them using the year by year approach and with constraint_exclusion enabled, I would expect my queries to be executed on a much smaller data set.

EDIT: 10m is a conservative number and the number is growing ~1m every month.

Comment: Sounds as if you are missing a usable index on `inserted_at`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have foreign keys pointing to partitioned tables currently.

There is [a “work in progress” patch](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20181102234158.735b3fevta63msbj@alvherre.pgsql) for this functionality, so it may come in PostgreSQL v12.

For the present, you'd have to do without a foreign key constraint if you want partitioning.